# Mocking graphql server

Tags: graphql

I'm trying to mock my graphql server, so that when I query, it returns back mock data instead of going to the graphql server.  At the moment when I run my query against the mock graphql, I'm getting back this error:

`"errors":[{"message":"Syntax Error GraphQL request (1:13) Expected $, found Name 
 \"input\"\n\n1: query login(input: {userName: \"james\" , passWord: \"password\"}`

Here's my current setup:

**Query**

```
let query = `query login(input: {userName: "james" , passWord: "password"}){
   login(input: {userName: "james" , passWord: "password"})
}`;
```

**Schema**

```
const typeDefs = `
type loginCrendentialsType {
  data: String
}
input loginInputType{
  userName: String!
  passWord: String!
}
type RootQuery {
  login(input: loginInputType): [loginCrendentialsType]
}
schema {
  query: RootQuery
}
`;
```

**Mock**

```
const mocks = {
 login: (loginInputType) => ({
   data: mockDB.getUser(loginInputType.userName, loginInputType.passWord)
 })
};
```

**setup**

```
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
 typeDefs
});

addMockFunctionsToSchema({
 schema,
 mocks,
});

graphql(schema,query).then((result) => {
  console.log("reachedhere  " + JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

Comment: I think when you provide input variables, it must be mutation not query??

Comment: btw check out graphql-faker: https://github.com/APIs-guru/graphql-faker
It uses faker.js to fake GraphQL server. Also it supports extend mode for mixing real server data with faked.

Answer (score 2):

I think when you provide input variables, it must be mutation not query??

use the variable to store the input object and assign it the `$input`

```
let query = `query login($input: {input: {userName: "james" , passWord: "password"} }){
   login(input: $input)
}`;
```

OR

```
let query = `query login{
   login(input: {userName: "james" , passWord: "password"})
}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GraphQL Tools from the Apollo team to help you mock things out
https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools

Your query was wrong and needed to be in a variable as answered by @p0k8_